# creating array dynamically

Tags: php, sql-server, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to creates the array dynamically like below using php

```
 $data =    array(
  array("date" => "1/2/2012", "sentstatus" => "0", "mobile" => "14578998"),
      array("date" => "21/2/2012", "sentstatus" => "1", "mobile" => "14668998"),
      array("date" => "1/5/2012", "sentstatus" => "1", "mobile" => "14598998"),
      array("date" => "1/6/2012", "sentstatus" => "0", "mobile" => "14578748"),
);
```

Below is my PHP code that insert the sql server data into array but the problem is that it the array is formed of only last result set row of the database table. I am not getting the idea to insert all database table row into array as shown above:

```
 $sql = "SELECT [start_date_time],[sent_status],[mobile_number] ,[play_file] 
         FROM [slice].[dbo].[tbl_message_detail] ";
 $res = odbc_exec($con,$sql) or die(odbc_error());
 $rows = odbc_num_rows($res);

 while($row = odbc_fetch_array($res))
  {     
 $data =  array(
         array("Date_Time" => $row['start_date_time'], "Send_Status" => $row['sent_status'], "Mobile_Number" => $row['mobile_number'], "play_file" => $row['play_file'])
    );
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting only the last row because you are creating a new array with every iteration. Declare `$data` outside of the `while` loop.

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
while($row = odbc_fetch_array($res))
{     
  $data[] =  array("Date_Time" => $row['start_date_time'], 
                   "Send_Status" => $row['sent_status'], 
                   "Mobile_Number" => $row['mobile_number'], 
                   "play_file" => $row['play_file']);
}
```

Comment: thanks for replying very soon. thanks for easy solution..it solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

You're overwriting the $data variable at each round of the loop. This:

```
$data = array();
while($row = odbc_fetch_array($res))
{     
 $data[] = array("Date_Time" => $row['start_date_time'], 
                 "Send_Status" => $row['sent_status'], 
                 "Mobile_Number" => $row['mobile_number'], 
                 "play_file" => $row['play_file']
           );
}
```

should work as you need